# Sprite Delay

Tags: iphone

i have a sprite & a set of coordinates... I want my sprite to follow that path & its following but its so fast that i can see only the last position......
So i want to introduce delay in every new position.. so how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Short ansfer: NSTimer.  Update your sprite position on every timer tick.  Generally, you want to have a master timer/clock that fires X times per second and update all your animation logic based on that clock.  30fps is good for games.

If you're doing a game, have you checked out cocos2d-iphone?